# C++ Separated static field for each derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, static, crtp

For quite a long time as was thinking about solution to my problem and I finally came to point when I have no other ideas but to ask here.

I have following problem.

Short version. How to inherit static field from base class, but make it unique in each derived class and keep possibility to upcast those classes to parent class?

Long version. I need to create some kind of basic interface for set of classes. Each of this classes need to have one static field and one static method. But I want to be able to pass all those classes as parameters to one universal function which uses those static members. So I was thinking about inheriting them all from one base class.

But of course I can't simply inherit static members and expect them to be unique in each child class. I was trying to use Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP), but it forces me to make this universal function template too and directly give it class name during each call. That's not good for me.

Also I have problems with making CRTP works when more than one level of inheritance is used (i.e. when I want to derive one more class from class derived from this template base class). Is there any way to achieve what I need?

I know that similar questions were already asked but in most of them authors were glad with CRTP. For me it doesn't seem like solution good enough.

```
 //pseudo-code for what I need, doesn't work of course
class Base {
public:
   static int x;
   static int GetX() {return x;}
}

class Derived : public Base {};
class NextDerived : public Derived {};
class NextDerived2 : public Derived {};

void Foo(Base& a) {a.x = 10;}

int main {
    NextDerived d;
    NextDerived2 d2;
    Foo(d);
    Foo(d2); //both Foos modify different static variables
}

//CRTP attempt
template <class C> 
class Base {
public:
   static int x;
   static int GetX() {return x}
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {};
int Derived::x = 0;

template <class C>
void Foo(Base<C>& b) {
   b.x = 10;
   return;
};

int main() {
   Derived d;

   Foo<Derived>(d);
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for a template.

Comment: CRTP is the solution for your problem. I do not see any other way to have different static variables for each subclass. What is wrong with the CRTP solution?

Comment: Why you write `Foo<Derived>(d);`? `Foo(d);` should be just fine.

Comment: why keeping them in the base class? move statics to derived classes and use virtual interface to access them. you can use CRTP on the derived classes instead. Or use CRTP ont he base class and make one more common base, use virtual to access what you need.

Comment: @AndreasH. Woah. Such a simple mistake and I've wasted few nice days because of it. I must have heard somewhere about such way of calling template functions. I'm not very good with templates yet. I've just tested what you've suggested and it works like a charm. I can even derive another class from Derived and it still works. Seems like a solution :D

Comment: There are a few functions you have to supply a template type to like `make_unique` but generally you should never provide the template type.  Let the compiler deduce it for you.

Comment: @Serge I don't quite understand. By moving statics out of Base class I'll have to declare them and those virtual intefaces separatelly in each child class (even if they are to be the same in all classes, that's exactly what I want to avoid)

Comment: Why are you using a static member in a base class in the first place? What issue are you trying to address by doing that?

Comment: @Raddeo the question is - why? you either keep dynamic polymorphysm (as you seemed to have asked for) and use non-CRTP base class or you use CRTP base class and use static polymporhism then, you would need to template all function you call with this parameter. I think that the former is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that static variables must also be defined. So for every derived type that you need a separate static variable for, you'll need to define it as well.

Instead, you could use a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and a type-id hash to do something similar without the need to clutter your base class. Additionally, this allows you to have *any* type be used, example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#define out(v) std::cout << v << std::endl

static std::map<std::size_t, int> ExsAndOhs;

template < typename T >
static std::size_t type_id() // in case you don't want RTTI on
{
    static char tid;
    return reinterpret_cast<std::size_t>(&tid);
}

template < typename T >
void Foo(int _x) { ExsAndOhs[type_id<T>()] = _x; }

template < typename T >
void Foo(T& obj, int _x) { ExsAndOhs[type_id<T>()] = _x; }

template < typename T >
void Print() { out(ExsAndOhs[type_id<T>()]); }

template < typename T >
void Print(T& obj) { out(ExsAndOhs[type_id<T>()]); }


class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};
class D2 : public Base {};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // using explicit templates
    Foo<Base>(100);
    Foo<Derived>(10);
    Foo<D2>(42);
    Foo<long>(65535);
    Foo<int>(1955);
    Print<Base>();
    Print<Derived>();
    Print<D2>();
    Print<long>();
    Print<int>();


    Base b;
    Derived d;
    D2 d2;
    int x = 1;
    long y = 1;
    // using template deduction
    Foo(b, 10);
    Foo(d, 42);
    Foo(d2, 100);
    Print(b);
    Print(d);
    Print(d2);
    Print(x); // still prints 1955
    Print(y); // still prints 65535

    return 0;
}
```

This also avoids the need to declare each derived classes static members.

This may not be a good solution for your specific use case, but it is an alternative that achieves what you're asking.

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 1):

Does this CRTP style work for you?

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 template<class T>
 class Base {
 public:
    static int x;
    static int GetX() {return x;}
 };

 template<class T>
 class Derived : public Base <Derived<T> >{};
 class NextDerived : public Derived<NextDerived> {};
 class NextDerived2 : public Derived<NextDerived2> {};

 static int count = 0;

 template<class T> int Base<T>::x = 0;


 template<class T>
 void Foo(Base<Derived<T> >& a) {
     a.x = count++;
 };

 int main() {
     NextDerived d;
     NextDerived2 d2;
     Foo(d);
     Foo(d2);

     cout << d.GetX() << " " << d2.GetX() << endl;
     return 0;
 }
```